# When merging querysets using 'or', you cannot have extra(select=...) on both sides

Tags: python, django-models, merge, django-queryset

i think this is a simple and straight forward question, i have two query sets, i am merging them into one.
but this error occurred.

```
When merging querysets using 'or', you cannot have extra(select=...) on both sides.
```

### Code:

```
projects = pending_or_onhold | pending_by_manager
```

### Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/Pythonapps/ifscoatings\ifs_request_system\decorators.py", line 20, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/Pythonapps/ifscoatings\request_system\views.py", line 493, in dashboard
    return render_to_response('dashboard.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request, ctx))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts\__init__.py", line 29, in render_to_response
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 177, in render_to_string
    return t.render(context_instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 124, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 483, in render
    output = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 284, in render
    return nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 156, in render
    return self.render_template(self.template, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 138, in render_template
    output = template.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 140, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 134, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 483, in render
    output = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 830, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\debug.py", line 74, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 481, in render
    six.iteritems(self.extra_context)])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 606, in resolve
    new_obj = func(obj, *arg_vals)
  File "D:/Pythonapps/ifscoatings\request_system\templatetags\template_filters.py", line 54, in filter_project
    projects = safe_projects(project_list=_callable(MyDashboard(request=request)), request=request, filter_market=True)
  File "D:/Pythonapps/ifscoatings\request_system\lib.py", line 73, in chemist_pending_work
    projects = pending_or_onhold | pending_by_manager
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 234, in __or__
    combined.query.combine(other.query, sql.OR)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 544, in combine
    raise ValueError("When merging querysets using 'or', you "
ValueError: When merging querysets using 'or', you cannot have extra(select=...) on both sides.
[05/Dec/2013 17:37:05] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 500 655503
```

This is the select Exta that is creating error that i can not have.
this is the new error that has been seen. i just want to merge the both querysets.

```
.....filter().extra(
                select={"priority": "COALESCE(bm_rank, sales_rank, id)", "size": "order_size_price*order_size_weight"})
```

Comment: Have you tried doing something else?

Comment: i tried list(chain(a, b)) but that just gives me list, instead i need a Queryset

Comment: What's the question exactly ?

Comment: how to merge two Querysets  PLUS having Select Extra in them.

Comment: You can't have anything that the ORM can't turn into SQL. Try again.

Comment: yupp, doing since then. but not having luck, i think i have to try some alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Context:

I wanted to merge the two query sets and order them according to their priority.
so here is what I came up with.

```
result_list = sorted(chain(query_set_1, query_set_2),
            key=lambda instance: instance.priority)
```

Here `instance.priority` is actually ordering the records. But the result is not actually a Query set which I wanted, But it worked out for me.
I got List instead of Query set, but i have no query set operations to perform after combining and the query sets.

Answer (score 1):

Read again, carefully, the error message you post. It's Django who don't support merging QuerySets calculated (both of them) using extra select.

I have not seen the rest of your code, or  more code allowing me make a picture of the context you are working.

I'll  suggest you use some custom generator. And try again.

You can also try with raw SQL.

Comment: Thank you for answer, I believe you are right, we just cannot merge two Query sets with both having extra select.